# Centre of mass between two objects remains at rest if it was at rest initially given that external force=0

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

My question is

1. If there was a superdense particle of mass $M/2$ kept at some distance $h$ from a planet of mass $M$ and radius $R$. If the superdense material is suddenly dropped and if we assume that the only force between the planet and the superdense material is their mutual gravitational force then will the planet go upwards when the superdense material falls down so as to keep the centre of mass at rest?
2. Can this happen to earth?

Assume that size of superdense material is negligible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. If there was a superdense particle of mass M/2  ...... the superdense material falls down so as to keep the centre of mass at rest.

Yes it does. Newton's law of gravitation states that :

$$\mathbf F_{12}=-\mathbf F_{21}=G \frac {m_1m_2}{r^2} \hat r$$

Therefore the planet of mass $M$ moves towards the superdense particle with acceleration $a$ and the superdense particle moves towards the planet with acceleration $2a$.

> 2. Can this happen to earth?

Yes it does happen to Earth in the case of Moon attracting the Earth or Sun doing the same (they have a thing called [barycentre](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter) around which they revolve) . Though we don't see this effect for objects on Earth because **the movement of earth is quite negligible**.

Comment: The center of mass of the earth-moon system is a bit below the surface of the earth. It is that point that follows a smooth elliptical orbit around the sun.